# Unable to connect to db via console with a custom config directory path

Tags: plugins, records, migration, console

I've just used yiic for the first time for a plugin record installation and found that the `db.php` config file didn't seem to be picked up and I got database connection failures.

I added a `console` array to the file to try that but still no joy. So I edited the `craft/app/etc/config/defaults/db.php` with the username, password, table prefix and database name of my local install and it all works fine.

I've not tried this on a vanilla Craft install but I'm guessing that this may be because my config directory has been renamed to `config-mydomainname` as we are running 2 craft sites off of one craft instance.

That works by way of the following in the `./public_html/index.php` file:

```
define('CRAFT_CONFIG_PATH', '../craft/config-mydomainname/');
```

Is this change of path causing the issue with the console?

Comment: i had a similar issue with trying to nominate the target config (dev, staging, live) for yiic console plugins - instead of hacking yiic.php i wrote a simple, generalised front-end php script, which you might be able to adapt to your particular problem. see here http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10725/elegant-way-to-pass-configuration-to-yiic

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something very similar to this today. I have a custom path for plugins, as a result I could no longer run the plugin console commands because `yiic.php` is looking in the default path as specified by its defines. You need to let `yiic.php` know about your custom paths and unfortunately I don't think this is possible at the moment without hacking it.